# Capture html tag value to Smarty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty

Im not so good in smarty so I need help,

When I submit  this form using ajax :

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
        <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="15" class="input-text" id="code" value="" placeholder="code">
        <input type="submit" class="button-alt-gray top1px" name="code" value="Apply" onClick="search_code()"> <br>
        </form>


        <div id="cool_number" />
```

this `<div id="cool_number" />`  gives me (prints on screen)  a value lets say 10

and I want to pass or capture this value to a an smarty tag , I tried this:

does not work

```
{$p.total = "<div id="cool_number" />"}
```

does not work

```
{$p.total = "<div id='cool_number' />"}
```

does not work

```
{$p.total = "<div id=\"cool_number\" />\n"}
```

Comment: If you wanna assign the value after page is shown then Smarty is not the right tool here use javascript instead.Because Smaty is proceesed ony one time on the server just before o/p'ing your HTML

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch cool_number's value on the page rendered after form submit,
try `{$smarty.post.cool_number}`
documentation: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

if you need it's value already on current page (before submitting the form), you have to use javascript, because smarty is server side language